# What is the difference between (Supported Architectures) in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

There are four options

1- armeabi-v7a
2- arm64-v8a
3- x86
4- x86_64

Do I need to select them all if I want my application to support devices running from Android Q to Android Ice Cream Sandwich.
I want an explanation about them

Comment: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**armeabiv-v7a:** 7th generation and above ARM processors. Most Android devices manufactured after 15th of 2011 use it.(support armeabi and armeabi-v7a)

**arm64-v8a:** 8th generation, 64-bit ARM processor, Most of new android devices use it(Contains two execution states of AArch32 and AArch64 corresponding to 32, 64bit ,support armeabi-v7a,armeabi and arm64-v8a)

**x86:** Intel 32 bit, generally used for tablets (support armeabi (performance loss) and x86)

**x86_64:** Intel 64 bit, generally used for tablets (support x86 and x86_64)

> Do I need to select them all if I want my application to support devices running from Android Q to Android Ice Cream Sandwich.

Based on your description Please select all of them.

Here is a helpful article about it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/cpu-architectures?tabs=windows

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: `armeabi-v7a` and/or `x86` is NOT enough, you must also support 64-bit (Since August 1, 2019 ) when using **native libraries** (i.e. Mono). : https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for your remind, I update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Leon and SushiHangover, So if I don’t want my app to support tablets Devices, what should I not choose?, I want to reduce the application size as much as possible, and I know that selecting them all will increase the application size